# Extension of a scheme by the residue class field of one of its points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, deformation-theory

Let $T$ be a scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $t \in |T|$ be fixed, and let $i: T \hookrightarrow T'$ be an extension of $T$ by $k(t) := \mathcal{O}_{T,t}/\frak{m}_t$, i.e., $i: T \subset T'$ is a closed immersion with sheaf of ideal $\mathcal{I} \cong k(t)$ such that $\mathcal{I}^2=0$.

Let $T_n := \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{T,t}/\frak{m}_t^n$ and let $T_n' := \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{T', i^{-1}(t)}/\frak{m}_{i^{-1}(t)}^n$.

Why does there exists some shrinking of $T$ as a neighborhood of $t$, such that
$T_n \hookrightarrow T_n'$ is an extension of $T_n$ by $k(t)$?

This claim is made in the proof of Satz (Theorem) 3.2 in H. Flenner's "Ein Kriterium fur die Offenheit der Versalitat": Here is the precise statement:

"Sei $i: T \to T'$ eine Erweiterung von $T$ durch $M=\mathcal{O}(t)=$ und

Comment: When you say "extension", what sense do you mean it in?

Comment: This is usually called an "infinitesimal extension", for future reference. Right now, your definition of $T_n$ and $T_n'$ are both just $\operatorname{Spec} k(t)$, and there's no visible dependence on $n$ or relation to any shrinking of $T$. Is there perhaps something missing from your post?

Comment: Sorry, that should say $\frak{m}_t^n$, and analogously  for $T_n'$.

Comment: Great, but this still doesn't really make any sense to me - the shrinking of $T$ doesn't seem to be connected in any way to the other half of that sentence. Can you post the exact quote?

Comment: "Sei $i: T \to T'$ eine Erweiterung von $T$ durch $M=\mathcal{O}(t)=\mathcal{O}_T/\frak{m}_t$ und $a \to a'$ ein Morphismus uber $i$.  Mit $T_n$ bezeichnen wir die $n$ infinitesimale Umgebung von $\overline{\{t \}}$, i.e. $T_n=(\overline{\{ t\}}, \mathcal{O}_T/\frak{m}_t^{n+1})$, analog $T_n'$. Fur $n >>0$ is offenbar---wenigstens nach Verkleinerung von $T$ als Umgebung von $t$--$T_n'$ eine Erweiterung von $T_n$ durch $M$.

Comment: @user7090 - Let $T:=Spec(A)$ $k \rightarrow A$ and $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$ the ideal corresponding to $t\in T$. If $t$ is a closed point it follows from the condition $\mathfrak{m}^2=0$ that $Krdim(A)=0$. Are you considering non-closed points only?

Comment: The points I am considering need not be closed.